# Python request with access token not working

Tags: python, authentication, curl, python-requests, access-token

When I am running below API query using curl I am getting json response

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c' 'https://localhost:10010/v1/machines'
```

But when I am trying to run same query using python requests I am getting access denied error must supply authorization token with result code 403.
Below is the python code which I am trying

```
import requests

url = 'https://localhost:10010/v1/machines'
head = {'Authorization': 'access_token eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=head)

print response.text
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.
Thanks.

Comment: You've named the token different things and are sending different headers in general in each case.

Comment: @pvg Please elaborate. I am unable to understand. Please let me know how to correct that.

Comment: @ChetanGomase Try this: `{'token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c'}`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks! It worked!!

Comment: @cgoma Posted an answer for posterity. You can accept it if it helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the failure is because you are passing the incorrect header.

With cURL, you pass

```
--header 'token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c'
```

With requests, the same format is to be followed, and you must have:

```
head = {'token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=head)
```